# Can't ping remote device via Bluetooth Low Energy using routable IPv6 address

Tags: ipv6

I have a simple CoAP Server on a device that implements the BLE Internet Protocol Support Profile that I wanted to test using Mozilla Firefox + Copper plug-in. So far I have managed to connect to my device, and ping it using its link local address. Unfortunately, Firefox cannot access link-local addresses, so in order to use that I have to configure my device with a routable address.

I have this config file... /etc/radvd.conf :

```
interface bt0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    prefix 2001:db8::/64
    {
        AdvOnLink off;
        AdvAutonomous on;
        AdvRouterAddr on;
    };
};
```

Then I set an address in the subnet for the linux box, enabled forwarding and restarted radvd.

```
sudo ip address add 2001:db8::1/64 dev bt0
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
sudo service radvd restart
```

This is the output from `ifconfig bt0`:

```
bt0       Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-15-83-FF-FE-E8-EB-0B-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:83ff:fee8:eb0b/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:db8::1/64 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1280  Metric:1
          RX packets:111 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:116 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:8553 (8.5 KB)  TX bytes:10804 (10.8 KB)
```

Unfortunately something is still incorrectly configured. I can still ping my device using local link address `ping6 fe80::215:83ff:fee8:eb0b%bt0`, but when I want to ping it with its routable address, `ping6 -I bt0 2001:db8::215:83ff:fee8:eb0b`, I have no responses.

What could be the problem?
IS there anything else I need to configure?

**EDIT**
New radvd.conf

```
interface bt0
{
    abro fe80::215:83ff:fee8:eb0b/64 {
        AdvVersionHigh 10;
        AdvVersionLow 2;
        AdvValidLifeTime 2;
    };
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    prefix 2001:db8::/64
    {
        AdvOnLink off;
        AdvAutonomous on;
        AdvRouterAddr on;
    };
};
```

Comment: when I'm troubleshooting virtual networks I use 'route -n', 'ping I bt0' and tcpdump, 'ip link show' and iptables - usual gotchas include - the device is not up, firewall rules, NAT rules.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your radvd configuration is missing the ABRO options, required for your system to be recognized as a 6LoWPAN border router.

A minimal configuration would be:

```
interface bt0 {
    abro fe80::215:83ff:fee8:eb0b/64 {
        AdvVersionHigh 10;
        AdvVersionLow 2;
        AdvValidLifeTime 2;
    }
    #...everything else
```

Note that in *this* stanza you need to use the link-local address of the border router.

And of course your devices must be Bluetooth 4.1 (or higher). 4.0 devices will not work.

Comment: I have made and edit to show what my new radvd.conf looks like. I sill can't ping remote device. BLE dongle that is connected to my notebook via USB is 4.0, might this fact be a problem that I am not able to ping remote device using routable address but I can ping it using link local adress?

Comment: @AlBundy All the devices have to be 4.1 for a complete IPv6 implementation. See [RFC 7668](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7668) for further details.